# HTML5 video not autoplaying from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html5 video I am using javascript to load and play but since using this method the video will not autoplay. If I do not load and start using javascript the video doesn't always load it seems to be a 50/50 chance whether or not it is a black screen or it actually loads. Is there a way to autoplay from javascript?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var mp4 = document.getElementById('mp4');

  mp4.src = 'promo2.mp4';

  video.load();
  video.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divVideo" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <video id="video" controls autoplay width="560">
    <source id="mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that Chrome has blocked auto-playing videos from javascript, or at least has blocked auto-playing videos with audio. Try muting the video and then autoplay it. Add these HTML tags to the video element.

```
playsinline autoplay muted loop
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 0):

Set `autoplay` property to `true` in your javascript.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      var video = document.getElementById('video');
         var mp4 = document.getElementById('mp4');
     
         mp4.src = 'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4';
         video.autoplay = true;
         video.load();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divVideo" style="margin-top:30px;">
    <video id="video" controls autoplay width="560">
        <source id="mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually found that a recent chrome update doesnt allow autoplay if it is not muted, i had to add "muted" to the properties.